# Is it safe to use the name of a table as a parameter of a php function?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

The function searches the $variable named table using SQL as showed here:

```
class Search{

    `public function query(){`

      `SELECT * FROM $tableName`

    `}`

}
$object = new Search();
$object->query('tableName');
```

Is this a good practice or a door to SQL Inyection?

Comment: It's really the only way you can include the table name dynamically, because identifiers can't be parameterized. You just need to verify that it's a valid name before you use it. Whitelisting is one way to do that.

Comment: absolutely not safe. But you can test your parameter against fixed values to allow your function to work on different preset table names (if there are many, put them in an array)

Comment: Did you mean for your `query()` function to take tablename as a parameter? It's not written like that in your example.

Comment: The only definitive safe way to avoid SQL injections is by using **prepared statements**. You cannot bind table and column-names, but you should be safe it **whitelist** those.

Comment: What language is that written in?  The backtics are especially puzzling.

Comment: ok. thank you so much guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO, don't do this.

That said it may be perfectly safe depending on where your parameter is coming from.

consider mapping a variable to the table names, so you can verify that you are only building a query with a valid table name and not open-ended text.

A simple solution could look something like this:

```
public function query($tableName){
    $allowedTables = ['accounts', 'items', 'products'];

    $table = in_array($tableName, $allowedTables) ? $tableName : null;

    if(empty($table)){
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "Select * FROM " . $table;

    ...
}
```

Comment: *The short answer is NO, don't do this.* - Slightly contradictory when the next line starts with *That said it may be perfectly safe[...]*. So actually the short answer is *It depends[...]*.

Comment: @Script47 fair point... the short answer to "is this good practice?" is no. But "is it safe?" is maybe. And even if it is safe now, it is too easy to forget the risk later and tie that variable to user input or have another developer not understand the risk.

Comment: tahk you so much.

Comment: i have a question? with this code can i use it wherever? i would like to know if it is safety or that depend?

Comment: @Jensy As written, my answer is not a complete solution. You should add in additional validation of the input parameter (especially if it is coming from user input or other untrusted source). Also, I would confirm that $table is not empty before executing the query as well (edited my response to include that).

Comment: thank you one more time. i'll do it. i'm try know more about safety way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the safe way by "whitelisting" allowed tables. There are many different implementations depends on your needs. For example, get full or filtered list of your tables with:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

BTW, PHP has [a function for this](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-list-tables.php). Then check if input table is in the list.

I think it's safe way to do this.

Comment: pls can do you write an example?